# Error "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" near table_name

Tags: mysql, syntax, tablename

This is my Coding :

```
session_start();
include 'Connect.php';
$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$tanggal=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$status='Pending';  

echo $userid;
echo $status;
echo $tanggal;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'Order' (IdPelanggan,Tanggal,StatusOrder) VALUES ('$userid', '$tanggal', '$status')") or die (mysql_error());
```

After i run that coding, i got this error :

```
 `9Pending2013-07-27 11:25:54You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (IdPelanggan,Tanggal,StatusOrder) VALUES (9, 2013-07-27 11:25:54, Pending)' at line 1`
```

I wonder where my mistakes is..

Comment: what is the mysql data type for your `StatusOrder` column in your table? `Date` OR `datetime`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `order` then do it with **backticks** and not with quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `Order` ...
```

Quotes are string delimiters.

Comment: I also suggest to not use reserved words for table names... it is bad practice and will cause confusion for others later.

Comment: Thanks, the error for Order is gone : and i got this error :

`9Pending2013-07-27 11:36:26You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '11:36:26, Pending)' at line 1`

Comment: @Yah...gtLastName can you please verify this line `'$tanggal', '$status'` in your code and make sure it is not similar to `'$tanggal, $status`

Comment: @Yah...gtLastName: What data type has `Tanggal` in your DB Table? I guess it is `date`. But you are trying to insert a `datetime`. That won't work.

Comment: @Yah...gtLastName: If I am right with my guess then change `$tanggal=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');` to `$tanggal=date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Solved, it seems that i need to change '$tanggal' and '$status' into '".$tanggal."' and '".$tanggal."'

Thanks a lot for ur help ^^